# What is the best way to keep app.config and app.vshost.config synchronized? (or extend ConfigurationManager)

Tags: c#, debugging, configuration, configuration-files, appsettings

There are many examples of how to read/write app.config in Stack Overflow (and the rest of the Internet).  However the answers are not consistent, and neither the question nor answer usually indicate that the data may be saved in app.vshost.config during debugging.

Some answers even recommend using an XMLReader/XMLWriter to do this, which *shouldn't* be the correct answer since there is a specialized `Configuration` class for this purpose.

My testing (code below) shows that  `ConfigurationManager` reads and writes occur to `app.vshost.config` during debugging, and to `app.config` when running normally.

I understand why this is happening, but I'd like to find a standard way to read/write a config file when debugging and not debugging.  Perhaps this requires reflection, perhaps this requires writing data in two locations.

Either way, I'd rather not have my testers look in both app.config and app.vshost.config; I want to standardise on a fixed behaviour for all my components that use config (WCF Bindings, Tracing, Log4Net, etc)

> A non-standard implementation may
>   occur when an application hard-codes
>   the path and name of the configuration file
>   to read.  Then, during debugging, the
>   wrong config file may be read or
>   updated.

My working code is below (though many people *think* it doesn't work):

```
        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("AgentID1");
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("AgentID1", "test12");
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
```

Comment: aack... that explains why I thought ConfigurationManager was broken

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way is to simply disable Visual Studio Hosting process while debugging (`Project properties - Debug - uncheck Enable Visual Studio hosting process`).

Comment: What is the benefit of the hosting process?

Comment: According to MSDN: "The Visual Studio hosting process improves debugger performance and enables new debugger features, such as partial-trust debugging and design-time expression evaluation." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242202.aspx). Honestly, you probably don't need it.